# Bash script in bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, eval, substitution

I have a bash script that arrives like:

```
SCRIPT=$(curl .... | parsing...)

echo $SCRIPT > myfile
```

But when I try to `echo` it in a file, some parts get evaluated. (Variables are substituted if any are defined, the `*` character is replaced by all files in the working directory, etc...)

Can I prevent bash from evaluating any content of a variable, while still `echo`ing?

Comment: Quote your variable: `echo "$SCRIPT" > myfile`

Comment: Or else don't even create a variable and use: `curl .... | parsing... > myfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use double quotes for that. I'll demonstrate:

```
$ x='*'

$ echo $x
..list of files..

$ echo '$x'
$x

$ echo "$x"
*
```

Comment: Yes, seems to work. There were more quotes involved in the curl code before I simplyfied it and that must have been why double quotes `echo` didn't work for me then.